# Finding the Google+ post that links to my site

Tags: google, url, links, google-plus

This question is pretty similar to this: [Finding the Facebook post or page that links to my site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4817/finding-the-facebook-post-or-page-that-links-to-my-site). Obviously this time I'm talking about Google+.

My website has some traffic coming from a Goolge+ URL, like this one:

```
http://plus.url.google.com/url?q=<MY_WEBSITE>&rct=j&ust=1417089928139000&usg=AFQjCNEQyDY0HrEmdCDFFQpzzUrNQ2xnHw
```

Is there a way to find out what's the Google+ post that contains the link to my website? Can I retrieve this information from the `ust` or `usg` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give Google Ripples a try by plugging the destination URL into the following

https://plus.google.com/ripple/details?url=

But the share may not be public, so you may not be able to see it.

Comment: It worked! I can see all the public connections that link to my website